# Is it possible to include attribute into the label

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="string" type="String" />
<lightning:dualListbox name="Mainoptions"
                               label= "Select options from "
                               sourceLabel="Main Options"
                               selectedLabel="Selected"
                               fieldLevelHelp="Select one or more"
                               options="{!v.options}"
                               onchange="{! c.handleMainoptions }"/>
```

I got Lightning dualListBox.... Is it possible to put Attribute value into the label?I tried **label= "Select options from {!v.string}"** and its not possible. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append it eg:label= `"{!'Select options from '+ v.string}"`

```
<aura:attribute name="string" type="String" default="asds"/>
<lightning:dualListbox name="Mainoptions"
                               label= "{!'Select options from '+ v.string}"
                               sourceLabel="Main Options"
                               selectedLabel="Selected"
                               fieldLevelHelp="Select one or more"
                               options="{!v.options}"
                               onchange="{! c.handleMainoptions }"/>
```